# Using nested lists to create horizontal menue with submenu under it

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I'm creating a horizontal menu with sub-menus under it (fig c) but all I could get was fig a but I want something like fig b or fig c:

[image]

HTML and CSS code for fig a:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
ul li{
    display:inline;
    background-color:red;
}
ul li ul{
    display:inline;
}
ul li li{
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    display:inline;
    background-color:green;
}
li{
    border:1px solid white;
}
li:hover{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
</style>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
  <li>overview</li>
  <li>alarm
    <ul>
      <li>view</li>
      <li>config</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>log</li>
  <li>config
    <ul>
      <li>tag</li>
      <li>security</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The question is: how can I create an output like fig b or fig c? I want the submenus to appear right under their parent menu without the parent menu being extended so long.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with fig (a) what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the submenus to appear right under their parent menu without the parent menu being extended so long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Alex; check this link http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/9SH4S/ may that's help you.

css:

```
ul li{
    display:inline;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}
ul li ul{
    display:inline;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:0;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
ul li li{
    display:inline;
    background-color:green;
}
li{
    border:1px solid white;
}
li:hover{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: i am also happy it's helpful to you :)